# What exactly does ApplicationSession.setApplicationOptions do?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

From my reading of the documentation https://developers.google.com/cast/reference/android/javadoc/reference/com/google/cast/ApplicationSession#setApplicationOptions(int) and sample app,  if I pass a zero then the default lock screen and notification controls should show up. Is that right?

Why is it that running the cast sample app, or an app I wrote very similar to it, after the media is loaded I get no notification area controls or lock screen controls. Is there another magical call needed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It works with:

```
int FLAG_DISABLE_LOCK_SCREEN_REMOTE_CONTROL If set, the application will implement its own remote control on top of the lock screen.
int FLAG_DISABLE_NOTIFICATION   If set, the application will provide its own notifications in the notification drawer.
```

If your application doesn't provide a lock screen or Notification, these aren't necessary. (and the system default notification & lock screen are used).  These flags tell the Google Cast SDK that you are providing Lock Screen and/or Notification.

Comment: That is sort of how I understood the documentation. My problem is if I take the sample cast app (haven't tried it in a couple of months) and pass 0 because I don't want to implement a notification/lock screen, shouldn't a default notification/lock screen show up then? because I don't see any. I've also tried it with an app I was writing and had the same issue.

Comment: There is currently no system level application to do that by default but you can install the "Chromecast" application from Play Store (the one that can be used to set up your chromecast devices), go to Settings and check the box that reads "Control Chromecast Devices from this app" and that should provide the default system-wide functionality that you want.

Comment: Ali Naddaf thank you for the info, that sounds like exactly what I want to try but I don't see that option on the Chromecast app. Is there something special needed to enable this?